# Seeking software similar to Google Earth Pro?

Tags: windows, maps, mapping

Are there other software products similar to Google Earth Pro?

I am looking for a recommendation that:

- Can import an image to the software to overlay an exist imagery.
- Must have historical imagery
- Must have toolbox that allow me to use slider bar
- Open source or free
- Can be online
- Must have 3D terrain

I have ArcGIS Earth 1.7, but it does not meet all of these requirements.